# make sqlite queries run faster with java

Tags: java, sqlite

so  I am working on a project 
in a part of the project we must read data from excel file and store it in database
we use `sqlite` with Java `JDBC` but the data is big more that 25 thousands line
as shown here

```
`{stm = conn.createStatement();
            //Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
           int hour=0;
            Row row;
            String collegename;
            String coursename;
            int courseSec;
            int courseid;
            String lecturer;
            try{stm.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE temp_table;");}
            catch(Exception e){}
            stm.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE \"temp_table\" (\n" +
"\"college_name\"  TEXT,\n" +
"\"course_id\"  INTEGER,\n" +
"\"course_sec\"  INTEGER,\n" +
"\"course_name\"  TEXT,\n" +
"\"lecturer\"  TEXT\n" +
")\n" +
";");
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                collegename=row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                courseid=(int)row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
                courseSec=(int)row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue();
                coursename=row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                lecturer = row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue();
                stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp_table(\"college_name\" , \"course_id\" , \"course_sec\" , \"course_name\" , \"lecturer\") "
                        + "VALUES(\"" + collegename + "\" ," + courseid + " , " + courseSec + " , \"" + coursename + "\",\"" + lecturer + "\");");
}
}`
```

and it takes over 30 mins 
but in `navicat premium` I can import it in less than 5 seconds maximum

cant I make it faster?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). They can help you make *working* code more efficient.

Comment: I don't want to review the code

Comment: I want a faster inserting process

Comment: "Make it faster" = having the code reviewed, unless you're looking for someone to give you a fully-coded alternative, which is *definitely* out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: It may help to not use JDBC's autocommit feature but set autocommit to `false` and commit explicitly.

Comment: I tried with auto commit and without same thing